# Rails: batched attribute queries using AREL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'd like to use something like `find_in_batches`, but instead of grouping fully instantiated AR objects, I would like to group a certain attribute, like, let's say, the id. So, basically, a mixture of using `find_in_batches` and `pluck`:

```
Cars.where(:engine => "Turbo").pluck(:id).find_in_batches do |ids|
  puts ids
end

# [1, 2, 3....]
# ...
```

Is there a way to do this (maybe with Arel) without having to write the OFFSET/LIMIT logic myself or recurring to pagination gems like will paginate or kaminari?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the ideal solution, but here's a method that just copy-pastes most of `find_in_batches` but yields a relation instead of an array of records (untested) - just monkey-patch it into `Relation` :

```
def in_batches( options = {} )
  relation = self

  unless arel.orders.blank? && arel.taken.blank?
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.warn("Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size")
  end

  if (finder_options = options.except(:start, :batch_size)).present?
    raise "You can't specify an order, it's forced to be #{batch_order}" if options[:order].present?
    raise "You can't specify a limit, it's forced to be the batch_size"  if options[:limit].present?

    relation = apply_finder_options(finder_options)
  end

  start = options.delete(:start)
  batch_size = options.delete(:batch_size) || 1000

  relation = relation.reorder(batch_order).limit(batch_size)
  relation = start ? relation.where(table[primary_key].gteq(start)) : relation

  while ( size = relation.size ) > 0    

    yield relation

    break if size < batch_size

    primary_key_offset = relation.last.id
    if primary_key_offset
      relation = relation.where(table[primary_key].gt(primary_key_offset))
    else
      raise "Primary key not included in the custom select clause"
    end
  end
end
```

With this, you should be able to do :

```
Cars.where(:engine => "Turbo").in_batches do |relation|
  relation.pluck(:id)
end
```

this is not the best implementation possible (especially in regard to primary_key_offset calculation, which instantiates a record), but you get the spirit.

Comment: it was a good try, indeed. But I'd rather prefer a non-monkey-patching solution, since I want to apply the said logic in a library which can be distributed by several projects, and I'd like to be as less intrusive as possible concerning code injection in AR.

Comment: Good point...so make it a class method. I guess your lib will be included in models anyway, and it should work just the same as long as AR is used.

Comment: Ended up using .limit and .offset ARel methods. I'm just saying, it'd be nice to have such an out-of-the-box solution for Rails.

Comment: @ChuckE you should post your code as answer. I'd love to see what you came up with.

Comment: https://github.com/TiagoCardoso1983/association_observers/blob/master/lib/association_observers/orm/active_record.rb

Comment: There's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391320/in-rails-3-2-how-to-pluck-in-batches-for-a-very-large-table