# In Rails 3.2, how to "pluck_in_batches" for a very large table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pluck

I have a massive table Foo from which I need to pluck all values in a certain field, Foo.who.

The array has millions of rows, but only a few thousand different values in the `who` column.

If the table was smaller of course I'd simply use `Foo.pluck(:who)`

If I use `Foo.find_in_batches do |a_batch|` each set is an Array of Foo records, rather than an activerecord collection of Foo records, so I cannot use `.pluck()` and AFAIK the only way to extract the `who` column is via something like `.map(&:who)` that iterates over the array.

Is there a way to pluck the `who` column from Foo in batches that does not require then iterating over each element of each batch to extract the `who` column?

Comment: for rails 4+, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/siannopollo/03d646eb7525f7fce678#file-pluck_in_batches-rb) for a `pluck_in_batches` method

Answer (score 15):

In Rails 5 you can use:

```
Foo.in_batches do |relation|
  values = relation.pluck(:id, :name, description)
  ...
end
```

Upd: for prevent memory leaks use:

```
Foo.uncached do
  Foo.in_batches do |relation|
    values = relation.pluck(:id, :name, description)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate about memory leak issue and how/why does `Foo.uncached` help? I'm also interested if this would also apply for Rails 6.0/6.1.

Comment: @GuiGS, it is not a real "leak". By default Rails will cache all query results, it can take too much RAM for this sutuation. This memory will be released later. 
`Foo.uncached` will disable caching. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-uncached

Comment: I see. Looks like in_batches already does this https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/85c6823b77b60f2a3a6a25d7a1013032e8c580ef/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L226 (at least for Rails >= 5.2). Not sure if it would will still apply to `relation.pluck` though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method to get the ids that were retrieved by the `in_batches` method itself, without need to run another query yourself.

`in_batches` already runs `pluck(:id)` under the hood (when `load` param is `false` which is the default) and yield the relation object. This relation object is created with `where(id: ids_from_pluck)`.

Is it possible to get the list of ids directly from the relation object via `where_values_hash` method, without the need to run another query in DB. For example:

```rb
Foo.in_batches do |relation|
  ids = relation.where_values_hash['id']
end
```

This should work on both Rails 5.x and 6.x, but it relies on implementation detail of `in_batches` so it is not guaranteed to work in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Foo.select(:id, :who).find_in_batches do |a_batch|
  ...
end
```

Comment: That will still create ActiveRecord objects, which I think the OP is trying to avoid for memory and speed reasons.

Comment: Not sure what above comment means..
For clarity, the `select` will alter the underlying SQL to only return the relevant values. `find_in_batches` already uses AR models, the question is how to limit the data being returned.
This is what I required.